# Clojure fails to call an interface default method on java 11 due to IllegalAccessException

Tags: java, clojure, java-11

I have moved my Clojure application from jdk8 to jdk11 (Zulu JRE 11) and it started to fail to invoke a [default method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) on an interface, whose implementation is machine-generated (and looks something like `#object[com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110 0x28466aa5 nil]`).

I do

```clj
(.someDefaultMethod iinterface-impl)
```

and get

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to public member failed: 
   my.IInterface.someDefaultMethod[Ljava.lang.Object;@172aedbe/invokeSpecial, from my.IInterface/2 (unnamed module @627551fb)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:942)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.checkAccess(MethodHandles.java:2206)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.checkMethod(MethodHandles.java:2146)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodCommon(MethodHandles.java:2290)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodNoSecurityManager(MethodHandles.java:2283)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.unreflectSpecial(MethodHandles.java:1798)
    at my.SomeService.invoke(SomeService.java:305)
```

Is there any solution? Thank you!

Comment: Depending on the interface it could be that it's part of a Java module that is not available by default, it would help to know the type of the interface; also check this page for some tips: https://www.deps.co/blog/how-to-upgrade-clojure-projects-to-use-java-11/#deprecations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the error was not due to Clojure but due to the way calling the default method was coded in the proxy handler's `invoke`:

```java
@Override
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Proxy: calling " + method);
    // Default methods are public non-abstract instance methods
    // declared in an interface.
    if (((method.getModifiers() & (Modifier.ABSTRACT | Modifier.PUBLIC | Modifier.STATIC)) ==
            Modifier.PUBLIC) && method.getDeclaringClass().isInterface()) {
    // see https://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2014/03/27/java-8-default-interface-methods-and-jdk-dynamic-proxies/
    final Constructor<MethodHandles.Lookup> constructor = MethodHandles.Lookup.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.class, int.class);
        if (!constructor.isAccessible()) {
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
        }
        final Class<?> declaringClass = method.getDeclaringClass();
        return constructor.newInstance(declaringClass, MethodHandles.Lookup.PRIVATE)
                .unreflectSpecial(method, declaringClass)
                .bindTo(proxy)
                .invokeWithArguments(args);

    }
    return null;
}
```